# Application not working with Vserv AdNotification failure method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working over vserv Ad integration and want to change the color of my view when the application has been notified with Ad failed notification, but I have failed to do.

Please find the error in the code snippet appended below.

```
- (void)adFailedNotification:(VservAdView*)vservAd
{
    NSLog(@"###########adFailedNotification############");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: For those that don't know what `vserv Ad integration` please could you include a link or something.

Comment: plz find the link below http://www.vserv.mobi/downloads-developer-resources-appwrapper.html